# is there a better way of writing folling code in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to write a function that will fetch one column from mysql & return it. some how I am not able to write get_hash() function. Further is it safe to use $GLOBALS?

```
<?php
    //Create Database Connection 
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "developer";
    $dbpass = "abc";
    $dbname = "abc";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

    //Test Connection`enter code here`
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Connection Failed" . 
            mysqli_connect_error() . 
            "(" . mysqli_connect_errorno() . ")"
        );  
    }

    // Query
    $query = "SELECT tweet FROM twc_hashtag";


    // Fetch Data
    function get_hash() {   
        if ($result=mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connection'], $GLOBALS['query'])){  

                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
                    //echo "<tr>";
                    //echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
                    //echo "</tr>";
                    return $row[0];
                }   
            }

        //Test Query Error
        if(!$result){
            die("Database Query Failed" . mysqli_error($GLOBALS['connection'])); 
        }   

    }


    //Close The Connection
    mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

I need to fetch the data in a different php file & then pass that data to a javascript function. Hence I am going to call get_hash(); from a different php file.

Comment: What is not working, exactly?

Comment: I'd recommend actually calling the get_hash() function ___before___ you close the database connection

Comment: `global` and `$GLOBALS` are a sign of doing it wrong.  They should never be necessary.  Pass `$connection` and `$query` to your function through its argument list.  That's why it's there.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /var/www/html/himanshu/db_fetch.php on line 23 Warning: mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /var/www/html/himanshu/db_fetch.php on line 35 Database Query Failed

Comment: The get_hash() function will be called from a different php file. I can't pass the arguments $connection and $query to it because it will be called from a different php file.

Comment: There are two files involved in my project. index.php that has markup & a jquery plugin to draw the pie chart. The other file is db_fetch.php i.e above file. I am planning to call get_hash() from index.php & then pass this value to jquery plugin for pie chart.

Comment: The problem is because you're ending the mysqli connection before calling the function. As @MarkBaker said.

Comment: @Ali if I move mysqli_close($connection); into function get_hash() then it works but then connection will remain open. (The get_hash() function will not be called each & every time, it's based on certain events)

Comment: @Himanshu1988 Well closing the connection isn't really important unless you're serving the data to MANY MANY users, else it's automatically closed when execution ends.